# Strip function/print in python - why there is no difference for removing whitespace in end

Tags: python

I was just trying out the `strip` function:

```
>> a = "hello world    "
>> print(a)
hello world
>> print(a.strip())
hello world
```

There is no difference in the output even though the string has spaces at the end. Could someone explain why?

Comment: Can you share the outputs in both the cases. It is unclear what you are asking

Comment: How do you know that there is no difference? Have you tried printing something visible (i.e. non-whitespace) around your string to see the difference, e.g. `print("'{}'".format(a))` vs `print("'{}'".format(a.strip()))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference if you check the lengths, you just can't see it when printing;

```
a = "hello world    "

print(len(a))
print(len(a.strip()))
```

Output:

```
15
11
```

Comment: Thanks , it clarifies .

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a difference, you just can't see it because it's whitespace. Try to replace whitespace with a visible character

```
a = "hello world    "
print(a.replace(' ', '+'))
print(a.strip().replace(' ', '+'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Space characters are not printable, so there won't be a *visible* difference in the output. To see the difference, try adding and then stripping some printable character:

```
a = "hello world____"
print(a)
print(a.strip('_'))
```